# How to fire UILongPressGestureRecognizer quickly

Tags: ios

I want to hover a cell as soon as it is being pressed, but the press takes too long. I tried setting the minimum press time to .05, but it doesn't affect the recognizer.

Any suggestions:

```
if (cell.gestureRecognizers.count==0) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userCellTapped:)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];


        //add a long press that kills the tap if recognized
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *press = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userCellPressed:)];
        [press setMinimumPressDuration:.05];
        [press setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

        [press requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tap];

        [tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:press];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:press];
    }
```

Comment: I don't think 0.05 seconds is long enough for all the other gesture recognizers to fail out yet, so gestureRecognizer can't conclusively say this is a long press yet. I didn't see any published minimums in the docs either, but I suspect you'll need to handle it with your own UITouch invocation.

Comment: What does your userCellPressed: method look like? Did you try logging all of the gesture recognizer states that occur in there? There might be one like gesture began that you could key off of for this purpose.

Comment: The time interval is in seconds. The default duration is of 0.5 seconds. You can't decrease the minimum default time, as it does not recognises `UILongPressGesture`